# want to change the color of dynamically created button on specific id which is pass by the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

that is dynamically creation of buttons

```
var i = 0;
      var jj=<%=qsize%>;
      for (i=1; i<=jj; i++)
      {
          $("#buttonPanel").append('<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top:20px; " id="'+i+'" value="'+i+'" "/>'+'&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp');
      }
```

now i have a jquery array in which id is stored as 1,2,3..

```
var arr=[1,4,7,2,15,77];
```

now on a button click i want to change the buttons color permanently..now my question is how to pass the id dynamically as

```
$("#'"+id_name+"'").attr('style','color: red;');
```

Comment: loop through the array and get the id

Comment: Do you need to change background color of the button?

Comment: @ArunPJohny i have done it but it is not working as..    for (var item in right) {
   id_name=item; 
 $("#'"+id_name+"'").attr('style','color: red;');
       }

Comment: Yes @JohnR but my button id's in a array and i have to loop throgh array and assign id dynamically to the css .. how to do that stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var arr=[1,4,7,2,15,77];

        $('button').on('click',function(){

            for(var i=0;i<=arr.length;i++){
                 $('#'+arr[i]).css('background-color','red');

            }
        });
    });
```

above code should work
http://jsfiddle.net/pmddugav/